# Rails + Ember - Should Immutable data be stored in DB as JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ember.js

We're about to start developing a web app with an Ember front-end and will persist our data using ruby on rails as an API.  For the regular models that our users will perform CRUD operations on, we are creating regular rails models and serializing/deserializing them to/from JSON when interacting with Ember.

But, we also have some data that will not change over time.  The team is leaning towards just storing this data as a JSON blob within a single column of the DB.  Alternatively we could create equivalent rails models for this data and then create serializers for them, but the prevailing opinion is that this will not provide us any desired functionality.

Are there any programming principles that would help guide up to the best practice method?

UPDATE: Realized I didn't fully describe the data. There will be multiple records that we will store that originate from a third party. If we used the JSON blob strategy, the third party would submit their data to us as a JSON and we would just overwrite their previous JSON blob in the database whenever they updated their data. So the data is mutable from the third party, but not within our front-end.

Comment: What database are you going to be using? PostgreSQL has JSON support in the database so your JSON blobs wouldn't be entirely opaque within the database and cracking them into individual columns could be done via SQL rather than round tripping your whole database through Ruby in the future.

Comment: We are using PostgreSQL for the production database, so that's encouraging news for the JSON blob strategy.

Answer (score 0):

### **When To Store**

I would assess this with asking the question: 'Will I ever have another front end accessing this data?'.

- Could there be an app in the future?
- Does it make sense that an internal system might need this data at a later time?

If the answer is yes or maybe to any of those questions I would store it in the DB. If the answer is no and they are just env variables or structures there is no reason to add another database call to the front end of the app.

### **How To Store**

When it comes to storing data that doesn't change over time, like say, a list of cities or zip codes. I would store it in the Rails Model and not on the database.

1. You don't have to worry about database migrations when using different environments.
2. You can easily change the values and see their history with Git.
3. It reduces calls on the database server which are harder to scale than app servers.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough on what is being stored.  There will be multiple records that we will store that originate from a third party.  If we used the JSON blob strategy, the third party would submit their data to us as a JSON and we would just overwrite their previous JSON blob in the database whenever they updated their data.  So the data is mutable from the third party, but not within our front-end.

Comment: Yeah, I'd go to the database with it for sure as a JSON blob. You can create a model with it and use some meta programming to make it easily accessible via dot notation.